# Expo React-Native Метод getSize() возвращает неверную высоту и ширину удаленного изображения

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

У меня есть проект, в котором я пытаюсь получить размеры удаленного изображения с помощью метода getSize(), проблема в том, что этот метод возвращает неправильные размеры для IOS и Android. После многих поисков я не смог найти подходящего решения. Если у кого-то был подобный случай, есть был аналогичный плагин для него? и как правильно получить исходные размеры для Android и IOS

```
Image.getSize(myUri, (width, height) => {this.setState({width, height})});
```